# In an organized way and "having kept their weaponry"

Tags: grammar

Source: http://rt.com/news/170624-donetsk-militia-leave-slavyansk/

> “Our troops have consolidated at the reserve lines of defense, in an organized way and **having kept their weaponry**. We were prepared for this option, as we have to face tens of thousands of Kiev's military men and hundreds of armored weaponry units – which means almost all the battle-ready Ukrainian army,” Boroday said.

I don't know how to grammatically understand that part in a bold font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*having kept their weaponry* means they are ready with all their weaponry (weapons considered collectively).

The part of the sentence after that *comma* shows how the troops have consolidated there.

Read it this way...

> How the troops have consolidated at the reserve lines of defense? ~ They have done it in an organized way; they have done it by keeping their weaponry (ready).

It's a style of writing.

> Having kept their weaponry... = Keeping their weaponry...

Other examples include *having being told...*; *having said that...*; *having it done...* and so on.

Comment: So, basically that's an adverbial construction? I ask the following question: how have they consolidated? Answer: having kept their weaponry. Is that correct?

Comment: @user69786 - That's the basic meaning, but we'd never say it that way. As Maulik has denoted with ellipses (...), these phrases are used as part of a bigger sentence. The stripped down dialog would probably sound something more like this: _What happened during the consolidation?_ Answer: _They kept their weapons_.

Comment: @J.R. Exactly... thanks for the answer. I was off for a day. :)